# What does it mean for a class to "interface with the runtime system"?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm reading an iOS development guide. It says that "your own classes will often need to inherit from NSObject when they need to interface with the runtime system." I'm having trouble understanding exactly what this means. I mean, don't all classes interface with the runtime system in some fashion? In Swift, when should I consider inheriting from NSObject? What sort of operations constitute "interfacing with the runtime system"?

Comment: While a poorly worded question (meaning I expect this to be closed eventually), not *all* things inherit from NSObject. First (and there's many more examples one you think about it) let's consider the idea of a Car "object" with 4 tires, a model, make,  and year, and color. Now add inheritance... where does NSObject fit in? Actually, no where. Now consider the back end of any MVC project. Make it mySQL or CoreData... where does NSObject fit in? Nowhere. NSObject fits in almost - almost - the moment you consider UI. But the truth is, what does NSObject give you - or not give you?